# Remove Listview highlight

Tags: wpf, listview

I am using List View with WPF, i want to remove highlight color on Mouse Over, i am implementing this code.

```
 <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
 </Trigger>
```

Although it is removing highlight color but not completely, there's a little gray rectangle box on top of the List View Item, How can i completely remove this highlight?

Below is the image attached as well.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uvsi.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Altamash, to my understanding, the reason why the white line is there is because wpf is using the default Windows Aero theme which includes that color scheme. In order to modify it, you can write your own control for your ListViewItem

**Before**

[image: Default Colors]

**After**

[image: After modifying the color scheme]

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
           <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListItemHoverFill" Color="LightBlue"/>
           </Style.Resources>
           <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                     <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                          <Border CornerRadius="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  
                              BorderThickness="0,-1,0,1"   
                              BorderBrush="#dcdbd5"   
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                  <Border Name="InnerBorder" CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="0">
                                      <Grid>
                                          <Rectangle Name="UpperHighlight" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="Transparent" />
                                          <GridViewRowPresenter Grid.RowSpan="0"   
                                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"   
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                      </Grid>
                                  </Border>
                             </Border>
                       <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                       <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                           <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListItemHoverFill}" />
                           <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                           <Setter TargetName="UpperHighlight" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                       </Trigger>

                   </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
     </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe setting the style for the item container

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Control.Focusable" Value="False"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

or you can use Multi Triggers

```
<MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="false"/>
    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"/>
</MultiTrigger.Conditions>
```

Comment: I don't want to disable Focus because i may use different background color for highlight as well but without that gray rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was in setting classical theme:

```
        public static void SetTheme(string themeName, string themeColor)
    {
        const BindingFlags staticNonPublic = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

        var presentationFrameworkAsm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Window));

        var themeWrapper = presentationFrameworkAsm.GetType("MS.Win32.UxThemeWrapper");

        var isActiveField = themeWrapper.GetField("_isActive", staticNonPublic);
        var themeColorField = themeWrapper.GetField("_themeColor", staticNonPublic);
        var themeNameField = themeWrapper.GetField("_themeName", staticNonPublic);

        // Set this to true so WPF doesn't default to classic.
        isActiveField.SetValue(null, true);

        themeColorField.SetValue(null, themeColor);
        themeNameField.SetValue(null, themeName);
    }

    static App()
    {
        try
        {
            SetTheme("Classic", "NormalColor");
```

Source:
http://northhorizon.net/2010/how-to-actually-change-the-system-theme-in-wpf/